# Is this a valid uniqueness up to isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory, definition

I've shown around for a couple of times asking more or less same "uniqueness up to isomorphism"-related questions. Unfortunately, have to ask yet another one.

Say, there are distinguishable $A, B, C$ sets along with $f : A \mapsto B$ and $g : B \mapsto C$. Those conditions are sufficient to build up **unique** $h : A \mapsto C, h = g \circ f$.

---

1) May I state that $A$ and $B$ are "unique up to isomorphism" since there is a way to map them both to the same $C$?

2) May I state that maps $g$ and $h$ are "unique up to isomorphism" because of the fact that both resulting to the same $C$?

3) Finally, does the term "isomorphism" **always** equal to the "bijection"? Could any of the "unique up to isomorphism" be safely replaced with "unique up to bijection"?

Comment: Saying that $A$ is isomorphic to $B$ has nothing to do with $C$! Also, $\text{Hom}(X,Y)\neq \emptyset$ for all non-empty sets $X,Y$, thus between any two sets, there is always a map.

Comment: Are $f,g$ assumed to be isomorphisms or merely functions?  In what sense do you mean that $h$ is "unique"?

Comment: This question is not at all clear.  "isomorphisms" are the same as "bijections" only if we are in a category in which this holds.  If you are in a category in which the objects have more structure then an "isomorphism" will be expected to respect that additional structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **no** to all three questions.

1. $A$ and $B$ are *isomorphic*. You say that an object is *unique up to isomorphism* when it is completely determined by some (universal) property, up to isomorphisms (i.e. there could be another object with the same properties, but it would have to be isomorphic to the first one).
2. This question doesn't really make any sense to me.
3. This is a more interesting question. You are probably used to work in categories where the objects have underlying sets and where the morphisms are morphisms of the underlying sets. This is not always the case, so the answer is no. Also in the case where the objects have underlying sets and the morphisms are morphisms of sets respecting some additional structure, this is certainly not true (e.g. not all bijections between groups are isomorphisms...)

Comment: $A$ and $B$ aren't isomorphic if all we know is that they both map into $C$!

Comment: Just to clarify. By saying that the $A$ is isomorphic to the $B$.. is it just because of mapping to the $C$? Does not make much sense to me then: there is a mapping from empty set to an any other $S$. So all of them are isomorphic?

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic because, and only because, of the existence of a certain type of morphism $f$ from $A$ to $B$. Specifically, the morphism has an inverse morphism from $B$ to $A$ (inverse with respect to composition). So there is no mention of a third object $C$ at all.

Comment: @PeterSmith Oh, right, I misread. I thought that $f,g$ were supposed to be bijective in the OP.

Comment: I think your last sentence could be a bit nuanced; there are a lot of cases where the morphisms are just functions preserving some structure where it *is* true that isomorphisms are exactly the bijections that preserve the structure. For example every bijective group homomorphism is an isomorphism. A better counterexample would be topological spaces or partially ordered sets; not every continuous or order-preserving bijection is an isomorphism.